# How can I delete elements from list

Tags: java, collections

I have 2 lists:

first: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
second: {2, 4}

How can I delete elements from first list, which are contained in the second one?
In result I should have third list {1, 3, 5}

Comment: Welcome. Stack Overflow is not meant to simply give you answers. You are expected to make an effort then ask a question about a specific error.

Answer (score 1):

### Simplified version

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
list.add(4);
list.add(5);
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add(2);
list2.add(4);

list.removeAll(list2);
System.out.println("list = " + list);
```

### Complex version

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
list.add(4);
list.add(5);
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add(2);
list2.add(4);

for(Integer i: list2){
    if (list.contains(i)){
        int indexOfi = list.indexOf(i);
        list.remove(indexOfi);
    }
}

System.out.println("list = " + list);
```

The limitation of this approach is: it is only able to delete the first appearance of `list2` element in `list`.

eg: list: [1,2,2,3,4,5], list2: [2,4]. the result would be [1,2,3,5].

To delete duplicate, you can change `if (list.contains(i))` to `while (list.contains(i))`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: An alternative to remove all copies is to change `removeAll(list2)` to `removeIf(list2::contains)`

Comment: @sprinter or `for(Integer i: list2) do {} while(list.remove(i));` which is still simpler than the (unnecessarily) complex version of the answer. But since `removeAll` does remove all occurrences, I don’t see the reason to search for alternatives anyway.

Comment: `list.remove(i)` means remove the value at index `i`, not remove value `i`.  So `for(Integer i: list2) do {} while(list.remove(i));` won't work.

Comment: @jayzhou don’t confuse [`remove(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#remove(int)) with [`remove(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)). It’s an unfortunate design to have the same name for both methods. But since in my code, `i` has the type `Integer` rather than `int`, the method `remove(Object)` will be used and the compiler would tell us when we called the wrong method, as only `remove(Object)` returns `boolean` and can be used with `while`.